# Дружественные методы в шаблонных классах

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, дружественная-функция

```
template<typename T>
class A {
  int a = 0;
public:
  void func(A<double> second) {
    cout << second.a;
  }
};

int main()
{
  A<int> first;
  A<double> second;
  first.func(second);
}
```

> ```
> error C2248: A<double>::a: невозможно обратиться к private члену, 
> объявленному в классе A<double>
> ```

Попробовал сделать метод дружественным:

```
template<typename T>
  class A {
  private:
    int a = 0;
  public:
    friend void A::func(A<double> second);
    void func(A<double> second) {
      cout << second.a;
    }
  };
```

> ```
> error C4596: func: недопустимое полное имя в объявлении члена
> ```

Собственно, как обратиться к закрытым данным `A<double>` из `A<int>`?
Кроме

```
public:
  int a = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

В С++ нет способа объявить что-то другом *конкретной специализации* шаблонного класса, не определяя этой специализации явно (см. ниже).

Поэтому в данном случае проще всего просто сделать все специализации класса `A` друзьями, добавив в определение класса

```
template <typename> friend class A;
```

Если же пытаться как-то минимизировать "лишнюю" дружбу, то можно ограничиться

```
template <typename U> friend void A<U>::func(A<double>);
```

Это, по-видимому, именно то, что вы пытались сделать в вашем коде. В таком случае методы `func(A<double>)` смогут свободно лазить в любые специализации `A`.

---

Если же вы хотите, чтобы другом была только `A<T>::func(A<double>)` и дружила она только с `A<double>`, то без определения явной специализации не обойтись, что фактически потребует повторного переписывания определения класса

```
template<typename T> class A {
private:
  int a = 0;
public:
  void func(A<double>);
};

template<> class A<double> {
private:
  int a = 0;
public:
  template <typename U> friend void A<U>::func(A<double>);

  void func(A second) {
    cout << second.a;
  }
};

template<typename T>
inline void A<T>::func(A<double> second) {
    cout << second.a;
}
```

Но, я думаю, результат не стоит таких усилий.

Comment: Чем отличаются объявления дружественности класса template <typename> friend class A; от просто  friend class A;?  Сейчас скомпилировал-отличий вроде бы нет

Comment: @zhukov: Что за компилятор? Просто `friend class A;` бессмысленно - это дружба каждой специализации с самой собой и только. Не помогает: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1cd88bcf0cb94450

Answer (score 1):

А Вы уверены, что Вам нужны конкретные специализации в качестве "друзей"? Посмотрите, пожалуйста, пример:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class node {
public:
    explicit node(T _value)
        : m_value(_value)
    {}

public:
    template <typename U>
    void add_child(node<U>& _node) {
        // логика, не относящаяся к примеру
        std::clog << "добавлена дочерняя нода [value=" << _node.m_value << "]\n";
    }

protected:
    T m_value;

    template <typename U>
    friend class node;
};

int main() {
    node<int>   node_i { 1 };
    node<long>  node_l { 2 };
    node<short> node_s { 3 };

    node_i.add_child(node_l);
    node_l.add_child(node_s);
    return 0;
}
```